# How to save Visual Studio Load test results into database

Tags: database, visual-studio-2008, load-testing

I want to know how can I perform VS2008 load test from five different machines and store test results data into one place, for example one database.

It is load test that test unit test. I specify scenario and counter sets and I get result and reports that I can save as .trx files.

How can I save specific data from test result from 5 different client computers that run the same test into one database and still know which client computer is data from.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To run load test from several client computers you should use "Visual Studio Team System 2008 Test Load Agent" software on all of them and single test controller. Test results from all clients will be saved in a single SQL Server database.

Setup guide is available here: http://blogs.msdn.com/edglas/pages/load-agent-and-load-controller-installation-and-configuration-guide.aspx

Comment: Sorry can you also tell me how to use it. Does all machines need to have Load Test Agent installed or just one ?

Comment: All of the client computers should have Test Load Agent installed.

Comment: Hi I have one more question, how do I add agents to controller, it keeps telling me "access denied". I go on Add and enter agent machine name and wait it to be in status ready.

Comment: Sorry, now I have no Test Load Agent and Controller installed to try this :(

Comment: Sorry man one more question, does the system under test measurement includes attacks from other clients. In other words will I have different results on one clients if host machine is attacked from more clients.